How to convert a python character to a python object
I have the following python lists
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

listOfChars = ['feature1','feature2']
listOfBins = [[0,1,2],[15,20,30]]

I need to define each of the elements in listOfChars and assign them the correspondent listOfBins element.
For example, I'd like to get:
feature1 = [0,1,2]
feature2 = [15,20,30]

Notice that feature1 and feature2 have no quotes.
And if I print feature1 I get:
[0,1,2]

Does anybody know how to do it in Python?

I can see that you are asking for a dynamic way to create variables from strings. But since you have imported pandas, I'm guessing you may be looking for a way to organise a Dataset and access the features without having to deal with raw strings everytime. If so, you can try this:
import pandas as pd

listOfChars = ['feature1','feature2']
listOfBins = [[0,1,2],[15,20,30]]

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(listOfChars, listOfBins)))
print(df.feature1) # Access the feature without the annoying raw string.
print(df.feature2)



Also, d = dict(zip(listOfChars, listOfBins)) itself may be sufficient, if you don't actually need the dataframe.

If we just leave it at dict, we will still have to deal with raw strings, which is what OP is trying to avoid.

OP only seems to think it is necessary to dynamically define variables.

You can use locals to update the current "local symbol table", e.g.,
listOfChars = ['feature1', 'feature2']
listOfBins = [[0,1,2], [15,20,30]]

l = locals()
for lob, feature in zip(listOfBins, listOfChars):
    l[feature] = lob

print(feature1, feature2)
[0, 1, 2] [15, 20, 30]

Just to note, I'd be very wary of playing about with locals in "production" code.

The documentation for locals explicitly wants against modifying its return value like you are doing here. (In this case, locals() returns the same modifiable dict as globals, but you would run into problems if this occurred inside a function with a distinct local scope). There's no good reason to inject variables into a scope instead of just using an explicit dict, though.
